# Module to make a program in python

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I've been wondering if there were other types of window-oriented modules than tkinter (too simple in my sense) or pygame (too much game-oriented). For example, if it were possible to display things with coordinates and not Up/Down like tkinter it would be better I guess.

Comment: You can display things in tkinter with coordinates using [.place() geometry manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Asking for suggestions is not a good fit for Stack Overflow but your other question about grid layouts is a good question!

**Grid Layout with tkinter**

Tkinter, like other desktop window managers have things called layout managers. Layout managers provide a format for displaying/ organising components.

Using [this](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_layout_management.php) reference i have prepared a short summary of the tkinter grid layout

```
from Tkinter import *

colours = ['red','green','orange','white','yellow','blue']

r = 0
#generate a set of components and place them in specific cells with the .grid() call
for c in colours:
    Label(text=c, relief=RIDGE,width=15).grid(row=r,column=0)
    Entry(bg=c, relief=SUNKEN,width=10).grid(row=r,column=1)
    r = r + 1

#run application
mainloop()
```

**Produces:**

[image]